# What does varnish hit-for-pass

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

When we were running load test on our application that is behind a varnish 4.1 server, we remarked that after a server error (500 returned with `Cache-Control: no-cache`) we were experiencing a load pea on our backendk.

Afer diving in the varnish configuration we spot that line https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/master/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl#L157
:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (bereq.uncacheable) {
        return (deliver);
    } else if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
      beresp.http.Set-Cookie ||
      beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
      (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
        beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store|private") ||
      beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as "Hit-For-Miss" for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }
    return (deliver);
}
```

If a page returns `no-cache`, it will not be cacheable for the next 2 minutes, **even if the next call the the backend returns a valid cacheable response**.

I can not figure out why this is the default behaviour (since a long time ago according to the repository history...)

In my case, an error in my backend generates a 500 no-cache, then leads to more traffic, and finally causes a 503...

I plan to remove this rule but I want to understand it before.

Any clue ?

Thanks in advance
M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read

https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/hit-for-pass-varnish-cache

to understand hit-for-pass.